# how do I persistently remove from $PATH on macOS (Z Shell)

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, path-variables

I used a command of the form

echo 'export PATH="..."' >> ~/.zshrc

As a result, the path has been added persistently. Now, I want to remove it. How do I do this? I know that there are posts about this already, but none of the provided solutions worked for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `echo 'export PATH="..."' >> ~/.zshrc` appends the string `export PATH="..."` to the file `~/.zshrc`.

So, to undo this, just edit the file `~/.zshrc` and remove the `export PATH="..."` statement from it.

Comment: How to edit ~/.zshrc ?

Comment: Open a new terminal window. Run `cd ~` to go to your home folder. Run `nano .zshrc` to edit the file. Press Ctrl-X to save and exit.